# Adobe Illustrator CS4 Intersection vs Adobe Illustrator CS6 Intersection

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I hope you can help me. I work for a graphic design studio and we have recently upgraded to Adobe CS6. One of our designers who works heavily with Illustrator.

He has noticed, when intersecting two lines that, unlike Adobe CS4 (which we have also tested as a comparison) the two lines don't seem to 'snap'. They do not connect like Adobe CS4 did and always seem to jump about a pixel out.

This is a screenshot of the result when intersecting in CS6 -

[image: Adobe CS6 Failed Intersecting]

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening? I hope you can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things to check regarding snap.

- Snap to Point (View Menu)
- Snap to Grid (View Menu)
- Smart Guides (View Menu)
- Align to Pixel Grid (Transform Panel)

Any one of the above can alter snapping behavior. If moving from CS4, the mo0st likely change will be the Align to Pixel Grid option on the Transform Panel. This will cause snapping to the nearest pixel in order to help produce sharper lines for on-screen/web projects. However, if you aren't working on a project where screen sharpness is desired, it can cause an undesired snap. Simply select objects and uncheck the option on the Transform Panel. and when creating a new document, be certain the option to "Align New Objects to Pixel Grid" is not checked there as well.

Comment: Brilliant, the 'Align to Pixel Grid' from within the Transform panel did the trick. Thanks very much!